# package deployed function using SPECIAL characters (like %>%)

Tags: r, function, package, roxygen2

I've written a package (**myHelpers**) that *had been using* the following function:

```
#' Negate the \code{\%in\%} function.
#'
#' Use this for the OPPOSITE of \code{\%in\%}.
#'
#' @export
"%not in%" <- function(x, y) !x %in% y
```

In the past (last year) this worked fine with my package. But now (and I don't know why) with the following:

```
library(myHelpers)
df1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df2 <- c(4,5)
df1 %not in% df2
```

Produced the following error:
`Error in df1 %not in% df2 : could not find function "%not in%"`

I don't know if something's changed when I build the package using roxygen2, but this is frustrating.

When I simple add this to my global environment in my session, everything is fine.

Any idea on how to get this function (with the SPECIAL characters of `%`) exported and seen with my **myHelpers** package would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

EDIT 9-13-19 14:07 PST
I'm using RStudio and my shortcut to build the documentation (and the Namespace presumable) with Command+Shift+D. I'm assuming the documentation gets written as it's in the MAN folder for the package. BUT, I get this error in the Build pane:

```
Warning message:
roxygen2 requires Encoding: UTF-8
```

AND, when I look in the Namespace file, my function is missing (even tough I'm telling roxygen to export it (with the @export).

Looking for the fix...

EDIT 9-13-19 14:14 PST
FIXED
Added:

```
Encoding: UTF-8
```

To Description file...and *I had an error that I didn't see*. I was using:

```
@keyword export
```

Because I had been using `@keyword internal` for a bit with the function....Now, I changed it to the *CORRECT*:

```
@export
```

And I'm off and running. Thanks for helping with overtired academic discover his mistake.

Comment: Have you *exported* the function?

Comment: See Writing R Extensions [section 1.5.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports). In file `NAMESPACE`, write `export("%not in%")`.

Comment: It does seem a bit odd to have a space in your operator name. What R version are you using? How are you building/installing your package? Maybe show what the `NAMESPACE` that roxygen is generating for you looks like.

Comment: Interesting....see the edit